# What means "atomic" system call?

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, system-calls, atomic

I know that *atomic* is usually used in the context of *race condition* and means something like *consistency* and *determinism of the result according to multithreading/multiprocessing environment*. That's ok. But recently I read about atomic system calls in Linux and didn't understand what does *atomic* actually mean here, i.e. **how** this *atomicity* is **implemented**. Does it mean that this system calls simply use locks on the resources (e.g. open() on the target file inode) or there is anything more, may be some kernel guarantees? I think about disabling interrupts but not all interrupts can be disabled. May be that's enough because all interrupts used by the kernel can be disabled and others are too important and can interrupt our *atomic* system call?

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the system call. Citing `man 3 read`, which cites the posix programming manual:

> I/O  is intended to be atomic to ordinary files and pipes and
>   FIFOs.  Atomic means that all the bytes from a single operation that
>   started out together end up together,    without interleaving from
>   other I/O operations. It is a known attribute of terminals that this
>   is not honored, and terminals are explicitly (and implicitly
>   permanently)    excepted,  making  the  behavior  unspecified.  The
>   behavior for other device types is also left unspecified, but the
>   wording is intended to imply that future standards    might choose to
>   specify atomicity (or not).

Obviously, this only applies to IO operations.

Comment: I know about FIFOs and my question about how this _atomicity_ work inside.