# Is stat() atomic with respect to the file system

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a collection of executables that regularly update a collection of files every couple of minutes 24/7. I am thinking about writing a single monitoring program that will continuously check the last write time (using the function `stat()`) of all these files so that if any have not been updated recently enough it can ring an alarm. My concern though is that perhaps the very act of calling stat() may cause a program that is attempting to write to that file, to fail. Need I worry?... and if so is there an alternative way to achieve my goal?

Comment: All system calls are atomic, and `stat()`doesn't have any effect on programs writing to the file, but there is no connection between these two facts. And `stat()` is part of the C library, not [tag:winapi]: but if you're concerned about *timeliness* and *Windows* you need to know that directory entries aren't updated with every write: for example the size and last-modified fields. Very confused question.

Comment: File system sounds like the wrong tool for the entire problem.

Comment: @user207421: I don't know how you could claim there was no connection. For example if stat() was not atomic then the process of one program calling stat() could cause fopen() to fail in another program.

Comment: @David Hefferman: I have a collection of six executables all busy creating/updating files 24/7. On average once every three or four days one will fail in some way. If one fails I need to manually intervene as soon as possible. How could this be done without checking the files they produce?

Comment: @user207421 "_All system calls are atomic_" How?

Comment: @user207421: Re: "Cause it to fail how?" - well it may not be possible in reality - it depends on how stat() and the OS are written - which I don't know all the details of, hence my question. But I'm imagining a scenario in which my_monitor.exe calls stat("example.txt"), then stat() opens the file and begins gathering the required data from the HDD.... mean time other_program.exe calls fopen(example.txt) but fopen() fails because stat() is busy with the file.

Comment: @curiousguy For example, if you write to a socket in blocking mode, and there are no interrupts, the data of that write cannot be interleaved with up the data of another write to the same socket.

Comment: @Mick Not only does 'atomic' have nothing to do with this question, it is in fact the *solution* to this question. Your nameless dread of a system call which reads a directory somehow magically interfering with a write to a file in that directory cannot possibly be a real concern. If that didn't work, nothing would work. Re your example, `stat()` *isn't* 'busy with the file', it is busy with the directory, but in any case as long as `stat()` and `open()` *are* atomic they cannot possibly interfere with each other. *This is the meaning of atomic.*

Comment: @curiousguy Yes, atomicity of system calls is an important goal, and it's usually achieved.  See [What means “atomic” system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185304/what-means-atomic-system-call) and [Is every system call an atomic operation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476329/is-every-system-call-an-atomic-operation).

Comment: How exactly do your applications fail? Are they crashing? In that case you have several options; neither one requires you to poll file system metadata. Are those apps just stopping to produce data? In that case, you're going to have to fix those applications.

Comment: @IInspectable: the apps gather information from many sources - including scraping some third party websites. If some data on a scraped website is goofy then my programs could either crash or may halt with a message like "I can not deal with this goofy data". Sometimes the program is just suspicious about some data and wants me to double check manually... Like "Is this man's name *really* Mr Qwerty?". If the exact nature and location of the goofiness was the same every time then I could code up a solution - but there will always be new rare things that I have not catered for.

Comment: Do you control the code for those applications? If so, you can easily implement a consistent way to report inability to deal with their input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a `stat` call can be thought of as atomic, in that all the information it returns is guaranteed to be consistent.  If you call `stat` at the same instant some other process is writing to the file, there should be no possibility that, say, the other process's write is reflected in `st_mtime` but not `st_size`.

And in any case, there's *certainly* no possibility that calling `stat` at the same instant some other process is writing to the file could cause that other process to fail. (That would be a serious and quite unacceptable bug in the operating system -- one of an OS'es main jobs is to ensure that unrelated processes can't accidentally interact with each other in such ways.  This lack-of-interference property isn't usually what we mean by "atomic", though.)

With that said, though, the usual way to monitor a process is via its process ID.  And there are probably plenty of prewritten packages out there to help you manage one or more processes that are supposed to run continuously, giving you clean start/stop and monitoring capabilities.  (See [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/overview.html) as an example.  I know nothing about this package and am not recommending it; it's just the first one I came across in a web search.)

Another possibility, if you have any kind of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism set up between your processes, is to set up a periodic [heartbeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(computing)) that each one publishes, so that a [watchdog timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) somewhere can detect a process dying.

If you want to keep monitoring your processes by the timeliness of the files they write, though, that sounds like a perfectly fine technique also.